# Is surjective strictly contracting linear map between Hilbert spaces a bijection?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are Hilbert spaces and $T:U\rightarrow V$ is a surjective continuous linear map with $0<\|{T}\|<1$. How to prove $T$ is injective?

Comment: You cannot prove that without additional hypotheses.  Consider a shift map on $\ell^2$ followed by e.g. a simple uniform contraction.

Comment: @hardmath hi, I make a mistake in stating the problem. The norm of the map is strictly less than 1

Comment: Having a norm strictly less than $1$ doesn't prevent $T$ from having a nontrivial kernel (which means not injective for a linear map)

Answer (score 1):

If this were true then *any* bounded surjective operator would be injective: Say $T$ is bounded and surjective. Then $T\ne0$, so $||T||>0$. If $a>0$ is small enough then $||aT||<1$, so  $aT$ is injective, hence $T$ is injective.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else unsure, it's not the case that every bounded surjective operator is injective: take backward shifts in $\ell^2$, for instance.